# JS Regexp back reference

Tags: javascript, regex

Lets say we have a simple alghoritm for highlighting search results:

```
var patt = new RegExp(result+"(?=\\s|\\.|,|<)(?! type=| class=| id=| src=)","gi");
var highlighted = unhighlighted.replace(patt,"<span style='border:1px solid #3399FF;'>"+result+"</span>" )
```

This works, but how do I transfer the capitalization of the text. Can I reference the matched word or phrase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use capturing groups and backreferencing to achieve this. This can be done like tihs

```
var patt = new RegExp("(" + result + ")" +"(?=\\s|\\.|,|<)(?! type=| class=| id=| src=)","gi");
var highlighted = unhighlighted.replace(patt,"<span style='border:1px solid #3399FF;'>$1</span>");
```

Comment: @BobbyMarinoff MY mistake. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Got it - same as Yadala's but the $1 is in the string:

```
var patt = new RegExp("(" + result + ")" +"(?=\\s|\\.|,|<)(?! type=| class=| id=| src=)","gi");
var highlighted = unhighlighted.replace(patt,"<span style='border:1px solid #3399FF;'>$1</span>");
```